# Two ViewModels for one View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am developing a Web-App using ASP.NET MVC and I've been trying to avoid  using the ViewBag, therefore I created few viewmodels to populate my drop-downs and in general to pass the data I need in my views. At the same time I would like to keep the data binding clean and avoid properties that will not be bound to (without using include/exclude attributes) and I've been told that obviously returnmodels are great for that purpose.

So is creating two independent models for one view a bad idea? One with all the data that needs to be displayed and another one only with the fields from my form or is this an excess of form over substance and should I reconsider changing my design?

Edit: A quick example because I'm not too good at explaining

```
class ViewModelA{ // passed to the view and then bound to when form is submitted
    List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> DropDownValues; // will be always empty while databinding
    int SelectedValue; // will be always 0 when passed to the view
    ...
}
```

Should I replace ViewModelA with

```
class ViewModelB{ // contains data passed to the view
    List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> DropDownValues;
    ...
}


class ReturnModel{ // contains data returned from the view
    int SelectedValue;
    ...
}
```

Obviously here I could just bind directly to my model but let's assume it's more complex and the data has to be processed before saved.

Comment: Your view model has all the properties the view needs, what exactly is the confusion here?

Comment: Yes it does, but at the same it has many unnecessary fields that the data binder might have to deal with, so should i create another one just for the post data or just let it be?

Comment: Why would your view model have unnecessary fields in it?

Comment: Because when I pass data to the View I populate my drop-downs from it etc. so that property will be never bound to and will remain null

Comment: You know that a class can have properties that are an instance of a class? Put them into another class and that is the VM of your view

Comment: Seems you are confused by ViewModel and ReturnModel. The ViewModel contains everything you need to build the View. The ReturnModel (the one the View will post back) contains only the form data

Comment: Yes, precisely what I was talking about, yet I called the ReturnModel as ViewModel too. So is a good idea to create a ViewModel to pass the data and then a ReturnModel to bind all of my form fields? Or is this excessive?

Comment: I bind **all** fields with the ViewModel and the ReturnModel is used in the POST method. Thats it

Comment: What do you mean _has many unnecessary fields that the data binder might have to deal with_? I the `DefaultModelBinder` only 'deals' with the values in the request.

Comment: I know that. I mean fields that will be never bound to and are therefore necessary. So just in case I wanted to get rid of them because what if I send some request that will contain one of those fields that I don't want the data binder to bind to?

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about something like the [`Bind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute?

Comment: I provided an example for more clarity. I would like to avoid the Bind attribute,

Comment: You seem to be implying that using `ViewModelA` is "bad" in some way, but it really isn't.

Comment: Based on your edit. No. Your property should be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DropDownValues` and you need to post back and bind to `ViewModelA` so that you can repopulate `DropDownValues` if `ModelState` is invalid and you need to return the view. You also need `int SelectedValue` for editing existing objects.

Comment: I see, I indeed did not take validation into account. Thank you.

Comment: @StephenMuecke There is no need to post back the `DropDownValues` property (and waste bandwidth). When you have to show the view again, just build the ViewModel again and return the view

Comment: @SirRufo, I am not suggesting that OP 'post back' values for the `SelectList` (that would be crazy)

Comment: But then why should I return ViewModelA with that IEnumerable property? That does not make sense and will only confuse future readers of your code

Comment: @SirRufo, Its not returning anything for that property - it will be `null` in the POST method (and if `ModelState` is invalid and the view needs to be returned then it is repopulated) - both properties are needed in order for it to work correctly in the view)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Have a look at my [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/71f4bcd7e172b589fa7f3003f5e22c46) with a sample. It is very clear (also to future readers) what you will receive on POST and what you do not receive. And I have the ViewModel and a ReturnModel and a working sample

Comment: @SirRufo. Why in the world would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what you are asking. You are saying you have a viewmodel with, lets say, these properties: Age, Name, CountryOfResidence (for dropdown), and a few more properties. But when you create a new person, you only post Age, Name, IdOfCountry to controller.

So your question is what is the point of posting the whole viewmodel, when it is not needed. Fair question.

There are many ways you can do this. Here is one way:

1. Create a base class with common properties (for posting)
2. Create a derived class with more properties for the view.

Some people will refer to 1 as Data Transfer Object (DTO). These DTO's will be shared for communication between presentation layer, service layer, business layer, data access layer etc.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I am asking about. Althought I merely want to know if this is a good idea or is having two models - one for posting (or DTO as you called it) and one as viewmodel to pass data to the view - considered bad practice.

Comment: No its not bad practice. It actually is good practice because of the reasons you mentioned and because it makes the intention of the action method clear: I need only this object to do my work. I have seen action methods wherein people pass huge viewmodels and they only need 20% of the properties. Oh and DTO is a common term. Not mine.